# What is the correct Target Folder value to target the root directory of the app?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to copy a file from `Views` directory to the root directory of the web server solution. I am using release pipeline targeting web server with `IIS Web App Deploy task`. Before deploying I am trying to copy `app_offline.htm` file from `Views` directory to the root directory of my app.

So I have the tasks:

1. IIS Web App Manage
2. Extract files
3. Copy files: to copy app_offline.htm to the root dir
4. IIS Web App Deploy
5. PS script: to remove app_offline.htm from root dir

The problem is that `Copy files` fails to copy `app_offline.htm` to the root dir.

I have the following YAML:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Add app_offline.htm to /'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted'
    Contents: 'Views\app_offline.htm'
    TargetFolder: /
```

It finds `app_offline.htm` in Views folder.

However it does not copy it to the root folder, no matter what I put as `Target Folder` the `app_offline.htm` is not copied to the root.

Every time:

1. it is not able to copy the file (probably because not finding the `Target Folder`)
2. or reports that

> File C:\azagent[...]\extracted\Views\app_offline.htm already exist at
> D:\Inetpub[...]\Views\app_offline.htm

so any target that it finds it reads as the current file location (eg. `/Views/` folder), not able to map the root directory.

See the targets and number next to it to see what's its result report as described above.

I have tried Target Folder as:

```
/ <- 2

\ <- 2

$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ <- 1

$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\ <- 1

$(Build.Repository.LocalPath) <- 1

D:\Inetpub\[...] <- 2

D:\Inetpub\[...]\ <- 2

../ <- 1

$(Agent.BuildDirectory) <- 1

$(Pipeline.Workspace) <- 1
```

**What is the correct `Target Folder` value to target the root directory of the app?**

***** **UPDATE** *****

Screenshot of the app structure.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check the updated answer below and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the option `Take App Offline` if you are using the [IIS web app deploy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md) task. Select the option to take the Web App offline by placing an `app_offline.htm` file in the root directory of the Web App before the sync operation begins. The file will be removed after the sync operation completes successfully.

[image]

Yaml for your reference:

```
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: 'WebApp'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_app_offline\WebAppNet.zip'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
```

If that doesn't work, then you can do as you mentioned by following below steps:

> What is the correct Target Folder value to target the root directory
> of the app?

According to my test, the `Target Folder value` should like this: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Content\D_C\a\1\s\WebAppNet\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp`

Note: It depends on your application name, you can check the pipeline logs to see the exact path.

For example, my application name is `WebAppNet` in this sample. I downloaded the artifact and extract it; the artifact structure shows as below screenshot (So the root of the application is `..\..\Release\Package\PackageTmp`):

[image]

To achieve your requirement, we need to extract the artifact and copy the `app_offline.htm` file from `..\..\PackageTmp\Views` to the root of the application (`..\..\PackageTmp`). Then zip the extracted artifacts again because the `IIS Web App Deploy task` will use the zip file for deployment.

The following YAML file which is working from my side for your reference, just replace the artifact path and other parameters with your own.

Note that for the [copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml), we need to set `flattenFolders: true`, and for the [ArchiveFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/archive-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task we need to set `includeRootFolder: false`

```
steps:

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: true
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted'
    Contents: '**\**\app_offline.htm'
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Content\D_C\a\1\s\WebAppNet\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp'
    flattenFolders: true

- script: dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Content\D_C\a\1\s\WebAppNet\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp
  displayName: 'check the copy'
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_app_offline\WebAppNet.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_app_offline\WebAppNet.zip'
    artifact: 'WebApp'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: 'WebApp'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_app_offline\WebAppNet.zip'
```

You can add another task at the end of the pipeline to run script to delete the `app_offline_htm` file from the target web application wwwroot folder once the deployment completed.

Screenshots for your reference:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @nickornotto Have you resolved your issue by above suggestion? any update for this?

Comment: The file exists at `/Views` folder correct - because it is its original location. As per the issue description - I am trying to copy it to the root folder so from `/Views` to `/` which does not happen. `app_offline.htm` does not exist in the root so there is nothing to overwrite

Comment: @nickornotto Please try to specify the full path of the `Views` directory as the `TargetFolder`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Where am I supposed to check this path? Because the one in the `extracted` folder in the working directory is as follows: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Views\app_offline.htm`. Also it is the source directory, not the target! I understand that `Target Folder` is supposed to hold the destination folder - the one where to copy the `app_offline.htm` file - not the source folder, right? So in this case the `TargetFolder` SHOULD NOT be the `/Views` folder but `/`...

Comment: I changed the TargetFolder `/` to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/extracted/` and I got the message `[..]\extracted\Views\app_offline.htm already exist at [..]\extracted\Views\app_offline.htm` on the task run.

Comment: @nickornotto Can you please clarify the `root` folder here? Do you mean that you want to copy the file to the wwwroot like `D:\Inetpub\wwwroot`? or the app root folder? For example, in above answer, the sample webapp name is `WebAppNet`,  the `app_offline.htm` file is under `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Content\D_C\a\1\s\WebAppNet\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views`, so to app root folder should be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\extracted\Content\D_C\a\1\s\WebAppNet`.

Comment: To the root folder. The idea is to copy the files to the app root folder upon the deployment so the site shows maintenance page and the the file is getting deleted from the app root when the deployment finishes (but it always stays in /Views/ ready to be copied to app root for next deployment)

Comment: @nickornotto Can you share a screenshot of your app structure?

Comment: It's rather simple as already mentioned, the app_offline.htm is ready to be copied from /Views. Otherwise classic .NET Core structure. I have added the structure screenshot above if you need it @Andy

Comment: @nickornotto Tested the scenario and figured it out, please see the updated answer to see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I can't remember what was your oroginal answer but we are aware of Take App Offline option. However, I assume this will be a standard app_offline file while we want to have our customised app_offline message to appear while off line. I'll take a look at your other suggestions and come back with the result here. Have a nice rest of the week :)